# Android 10: How can I switch to external loudspeakers during a call (the screen is black and locked and nothing happens if I plug the loudspeakers)?

Tags: android-10, bluetooth-audio, speakerphone, loudspeaker

I have a Motorola "moto e" phone running Android 10.

Unlike in the case of my old Windows Phone when, during a call, it was enough to plug the 3.5 mm jack with 3 contacts of my external loudspeakers into that phone and the sound switched immediately to the loudspeakers, in the situation of this "moto e" the loudspeakers receive no sound if their jack is plugged during a call.

I guess that, while talking with somebody, when the screen is black and locked, I can activate somehow the screen of the "moto e" and, by setting something, direct the sound to the external wired loudspeakers or to a Bluetooth wireless speaker. **How can I reactivate the screen and do the above mentioned settings?**

(In most cases, the screen of the phone has to go black and be disabled by the proximity sensors because in 80% of the time I use the phone with its internal speaker.)

[image: Moto e incoming call screen]
Incoming call screens.

Comment: For activation of screen, try moving the phone away from your face (out of proximity sensor range); If it doesn't light up, press the power button, if the screen is locked, unlock and try connecting to BT speakers //not seamless but worth a try

Comment: @beeshyams , During a call, once going black, the screen stays like this even if I put it face up on the table. I had the idea to press the volume or power button but I was afraid that the call would end. Unfortunately, I can not do experiments during calls because most of them, 99%, come from people I do not know well and if something happens and the call ends they might believe that I closed the phone on purpose. There should be somewhere on the net some clear instructions regarding how I can activate the external loudspeaker, wired or Bluetooth. I can not find these instructions.